# flask web server takes data from client but it is not able to save it

Tags: python, json, flask, load, dump

I just developed a simple application that receives a kind of data from the client and performs other activities with it. In other to perform such activities, the app must store the data but that does not work. I am working with the Python Flask framework.

I tried to save the data with json.dump(), f.write() and pickle.dump() but the data is not saved in the server. The server is able to print the data, but not to save it.

The client runs this function to send the data:

```
 def set_data():
        r = requests.post(
            "http://mywebapp.com/dataset,
            data = dumps({"code": code})
        )
        assert loads(r.text)["status"] == "OK"
```

The servers runs this function to handle the data:

```
@bp.route("/dataset", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data_set():
    if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                    data = loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
                    bp.code = data["code"]
                    print(bp.code)
                    with open(file, "w") as f:
                        json.dumps(bp.code, f)
                    return dumps({"status": "OK"})
```

I am able to print the bp.code and it has a type class 'list'. The appearance of the bp.code is something like [1000000, [2000000]] which seems to be actually a list. Even though I am able to print the bp.code I am not able to save it in the disk. How could I debug what is happening with that specific part of the function responsible for saving the bp.code? I am not sure if that is the correct way to save something in the server. I tried putting the Flask Debug Mode in active but it does not display anything in the routes / or /dataset. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have an error message or the file is just left blank ?

Comment: the file is created, but it is empty. The only message I get in the client is the assertion error given by the line return dumps({"status": "OK"}). The error I get is this:   File "client.py", line 83, in set_data
    assert loads(r.text)["status"] == "OK"
AssertionError
How can I debug the python functions of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `json.dump()` instead of `dumps()`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried with dump but the issue remains.

Comment: So probably it's not an issue of writing. Problem seems to be in the assertion that returns nothing or an error. Try to use in your `set_data()` function a try: --> except AssertionError and print the error

Comment: The file is created but it is empty. So it seems that there is an error in the writing after the file is created. Therefore the line: return dumps({"status": "OK"}) does not return anything or something different. I do not understand your suggestion. Could you please tell me more about it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on `print(bp.code)` and tell me what's the type and the exact value of bp.code.

Comment: the bp.code is exactly this two-element list: [13761060917, [5182911257157]]. The type of the bp.code is <class 'list'>. Thanks

Comment: That's strange because I reproduced the code with `bp = [13761060917, [5182911257157]]` and works fine. Your file variable where is initialized and what extension it has? I tried it with a 'file.txt'

Comment: the variable file is initialised in the beginning of the whole code (outside the function). At first, the extension of the file was .json but I changed to .txt as you did but there is still the issue. The file is created, but it is empty. is there any implication if I have the variable or object **bp.code**?

I am working with big numbers. Here you have another example. [7096961625517110620385779594939307678783994876511807183141241819616730811977, [1005988646422854092540400640087902812775353830280401858478703096837632123650]].

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am newbie in programming. My Python skills are poor and I am not sure how to add the assertionError. I know how to do the **try** part, but I am not sure about the assertionError line or lines. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. 
I am trying in this way:

def set_data():
    try:
        r = requests.post(
            "http://mywebapp.com/dataset,
            data = dumps({"code": code})
        )
        assert loads(r.text)["status"] == "OK"
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(e)